# Is it possible to assign a setter function to an object attribute without the @x.setter decorator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, getter-setter

I have a dictionary of attribute names and functions used to format the corresponding values when the object is created:

```
class CoolClass(object):

    def __init__(self, **given):
        self.formatting_functions.update({
            "date": self.str_to_date,
            "price": self.str_to_price
        })

        for attribute_name in given:
            if attribute_name in self.formatting_functions:
                formatting_function = self.formatting_functions[attribute_name]
                setattr(
                    self, attribute_name,
                    formatting_function(given[attribute_name])
                )
            else:
                setattr(self, attribute_name, given[attribute_name])
```

But if I will set these "special" attributes like `date` or `price` later, the corresponding formatting function will (of course) not be executed. Can I do this somehow without explicitly writing `date` and `price` with the `@property`-decorator and `str_to_date()` / `str_to_price()` with the respective `@date.setter`- / `@price.setter`-decorator?

Comment: [This](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html) might be of some relevance to you.

Comment: Why do you *want* to do this without `property`? Do you not want to use descriptors at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have similar classes with different / more formatting functions, this is just a simplification to illustrate the problem. I _could_ use `@property` but it would produce a lot of redundant code; also I want to keep it the class very lean and flexible, so that new attributes and formatting functions can be added easily without modifying the code very much.

Comment: Well you could do it in `__setattr__` instead, and I'd recommend not updating the dictionary every time an instance is created.

Comment: @EliSadoff While this was an interesting read, I am not quite sure how to use it to solve my problem. Could you point me to a broad direction?

Comment: @Kaleidophon Considering the metaprogramming approach, you might want to use [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @EliSadoff and @Jonrsharpe! I just implemented a solution overwriting `setattr`:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if hasattr(self, "formatting_functions"):
        if name in self.formatting_functions:
            formatting_function = self.formatting_functions[name]
            value = formatting_function(value)
    super(CoolClass, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```